# Forcing gzip to overwrite a .gz file in C

Tags: c, gzip, execl

I am having a bit of trouble using gzip to compress a file from a C program. I am using this line of code `execl("/usr/bin/gzip", "-f", filePath, NULL);` to compress the file given by `filePath`. It works fine the first time (i.e. when there is no existing .gz file), but in subsequent executions of the program I am prompted whether or not I would like to overwrite the existing .gz file.

Am I using `execl()` incorrectly, because I am pretty sure that the `-f` switch forces gzip to overwrite without a prompt?

Comment: Can you replicate the problem outside of C?

Comment: I tried not overwriting it so that I would have `/tmp/file` and `/tmp/file.gz`. Then I executed `gzip -f /tmp/file` and it successfully overwrote the existing .gz file without a prompt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide `argv[0]` too. So, like this:

```
execl("/usr/bin/gzip",
      "gzip", "-f", filePath,
      NULL);
```

In your code, you set `argv[0]` to be `"-f"`, so it is essentially ignored.

*Gzip* is one of the few programs where argument 0 actually matters, as `gzip` and `gunzip` are usually (at least on Unixy systems) a symbolic link to the same binary, and argument 0 is used to determine the default mode. If your `"-f"` worked, it means gzip is default.

Comment: `argv[0]` does matter in this case, since gzip looks at the name used to invoke it to decide whether to compress or decompress. So the use of the program name at `argv[0]` is more than customary here.

Comment: @MarkAdler Thanks, edited. I kinda knew that, having used *busybox* extensively, so I did not verify now, I hope you're right :-D